# Naturality of Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I am currently trying to show that the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence converges **naturally** in the following sense: Suppose we are given a $\mathbb{Z}G'$-module $A$ and a commutative diagram of groups with exact rows as follows:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

Then the claim is that the corresponding induced homomorphisms on homology fit together to form a morphism

$\hspace{4cm}$[image: image2]

of spectral sequences. To be more precise, this means that the homomorphisms between the corresponding pages are compatible with the differentials and that the map on the $(r+1)$-st page is induced by the one on the $r$-th page.

Here is my attempt: I can use the following well known theorem:

**Theorem** *Let $R$ be a ring and let $C = (C_{p,q})$ be a first quadrant double complex with homomorphisms $d'_{p,q} : C_{p,q} \to C_{p-1,q}$ and $d''_{p,q} : C_{p,q} \to C_{p,q-1}$ for all $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $d'd'=0$, $d''d''=0$ and $d'd''+d''d'=0$. Then there exist two **natural** converging spectral sequences
\begin{align*}
 {}^IE^1_{p,q} = H_q(C_{p,*},d'_{p,*}) &\implies H_{p+q}(\text{Tot}(C))\\
 {}^{II}E^1_{p,q} = H_q(C_{*,p},d''_{*,p}) &\implies H_{p+q}(\text{Tot}(C)),
\end{align*}
where $\text{Tot}(C)$ denotes the total complex of $C$.*

Now in the context of Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre, I take $\tilde{F}_* \otimes_Q (F_* \otimes_H A)$ as the total complex $\text{Tot(C)}$, where $F_*$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}G$-resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\tilde{F}_*$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}Q$-resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$. I can show that the first of these two spectral sequences looks like
$$
{}^IE^1_{p,q} \cong \tilde{F}_p \otimes_Q H_q(H;A) \implies H_{p+q}(G;A).
$$
**My question**: How can I go from here? Does the theorem imply that all maps are compatible with all differentials on every $E^r$-page? If not, what exactly remains to be shown? Obviously I have to use the naturality part of the theorem, but I'm not sure what I'm allowed to infer and what not.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you know what double complex, when the theorem is applied to it, produces the LHS spectral sequence? Is that double complex natural in the diagrams you describe?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ronno. Yes, I know which double complex yields the LHS spectral sequence, I figured out the answer to my original problem by now. Should I take down this post you think?

Comment: You should post it as an answer! (And then accept it if there aren't better answers by then.)

Answer (score 1):

In a more topological approach the LHS spectral sequence can be consindered as a Leray-Serre Spectral sequence. For every short exact sequence $0\to N\to G\to Q\to 0$ one can construct a fibration of classifying spaces $BN\to BG \to BQ$ (see for example Adem's Group cohomology) and with it induced maps of fibrations. The result follows from general results of the Serre spectral sequence (see Fuchs-Fomenko Homotopical Topology).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am aware that one can prove it in this way as well. Back when I posted this question I was looking for a "non-topological" solution though.